# Producer/consumer doesn't generate expected results

Tags: c#, producer-consumer

I've written such producer/consumer code, which should generate big file filled with random data

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            String filename = @"d:\test_out";
            long numlines = 1000000;
            var buffer = new BlockingCollection<string[]>(10); //limit to not get OOM.
            int arrSize = 100; //size of each string chunk in buffer;        
            String[] block = new string[arrSize];
            Task producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                long blockNum = 0;
                long lineStopped = 0;
                for (long i = 0; i < numlines; i++)
                {
                    if (blockNum == arrSize)
                    {
                        buffer.Add(block);
                        blockNum = 0;
                        lineStopped = i;
                    }
                    block[blockNum] = random.Next().ToString();
                    //null is sign to stop if last block is not fully filled
                    if (blockNum < arrSize - 1)
                    {
                        block[blockNum + 1] = null;
                    }
                    blockNum++;
                };
                if (lineStopped < numlines)
                {
                    buffer.Add(block);
                }
                buffer.CompleteAdding();
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            Task consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var outputFile = new StreamWriter(filename))
                {
                    foreach (string[] chunk in buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    {
                        foreach (string value in chunk)
                        {
                            if (value == null) break;
                            outputFile.WriteLine(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            Task.WaitAll(producer, consumer);
        }
    }
```

And it does what is intended to do. But for some unknown reason it produces only ~550000 strings, not 1000000 and I can not understand why this is happening.

Can someone point on my mistake? I really don't get what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Where is numLines defined and why are you not leveraging numElements?

Comment: Is `int numElements = 1000000;` supposed to be `int numLines = 1000000;`? You never use `numElements` and `numLines` isn't declared anywhere. Please post [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There's a variable - `int numElements = 1000000;` - that matches up with the number of results you're expecting. But that variable isn't used anywhere. It's really hard to follow everything going on in this code to understand why the expected result is that many strings.

Comment: sorry. Copied wrong name. Of course it's numlines

Comment: Can you edit your code so it will run and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Seems like a very convoluted way to create a large number of random strings.

Comment: Always copy/paste literal code from an actual mcve.

Comment: Missing `{` after if (blockNum < arrSize - 1) ? Why does loop not have a matching `}`?

Comment: Sorry again. I edited my code so it completely matches my real solution

Comment: `Random.Next()` is not C#. `fileName != filename`

Comment: I moved my code completely to main. Last generated file had only 525780 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer

```
 String[] block = new string[arrSize];
```

is declared outside the Lambda. That means it is captured and re-used.

That would normally go unnoticed (you would just write out the *wrong* random data) but because your `if (blockNum < arrSize - 1)` is placed inside the for loop you regularly write a `null` into the shared buffer.

Exercise, instead of:

```
block[blockNum] = random.Next().ToString();
```

use

```
block[blockNum] = i.ToString();
```

and predict and verify the results.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I used same array, so it got recycled in process. Should have copied it before add. How have I overlooked such stupid error? Thank you very much